# Python, len function

Tags: python, text

**I need some help, PLEASE LOOK AT EDIT 2**
 This is code of huffman:

```
def printHuffTree(huffTree, prefix = ''):
   if len(huffTree) == 2:
      print huffTree[1], prefix

exampleData = [
  (0.124167  , 'e')
]


if __name__ == '__main__':
   huffTree = makeHuffTree(exampleData)
   printHuffTree(huffTree)
```

output is:

```
e 00
t 01
a 10
i 11
```

I need some function or anything which can count this numbers; for example if

```
 e 00
```

i need to count how many numbers is here: `2  (0 and 0)`

so output that I need :

```
e 00  2
t 01  2
a 10  2
i 11  2
```

Comment: Did you forget a "homework" tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For edit 2:

Using your data in `exampleData` and if `c` is the constant to multiply each by then:

`result = sum(c*i[0] for i in exampleData)`

I'm still not understanding the rest of your question.

Comment: @thaking: I realized reduce is horribly wrong for this, sorry.  This is what you want!

Comment: Well, I know that, but I don't know HOW TO GRAB data for every number of "len(prefix)" and then first and next "number" in "exampleData"


sum(c*i for i in data)

Comment: Neil, thanks for help; I would like to say, that c is not constant; c is number of 0 and 1, in some cases if there is more input, like  (0.124167  , 'e'),   
  (0.0969225 , 't'),   
  (0.0820011 , 'a'),   
  (0.0768052 , 'i') ...., there could be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4..., so I need to "grab" this number from "len(prefix)" and then multiply with exampleData..., but c is not constant!

Comment: You need to save `len(prefix)` somewhere so you can get back to it later, possibly by adding it to the tuple from `exampleData` like this: `exampleData[i] = exampleData[i] + (len(prefix),)`.  Then use `sum(i[2]*i[0] for i in exampleData)`.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, you need to add `len(prefix)` to your final `print`:

```
def printHuffTree(huffTree, prefix = ''):
   if len(huffTree) == 2:
      print huffTree[1], prefix, len(prefix)
```

**Update to answer the new question**

```
def printHuffTree(huffTree, prefix = '', s=0):
   if len(huffTree) == 2:
      print huffTree[1], prefix, len(prefix)
      return len(prefix)*huffTree[0]

   else:
      s+= printHuffTree(huffTree[1], prefix + '0')
      s+= printHuffTree(huffTree[2], prefix + '1')
      return s
```

**You need to test it**

Comment: Yes work! But how can I call now this numbers I need to multiply this 2 and 0.124167 (from exampleData, for e). I need this for every sign, for example: (2*0.124167+2*0.0969225+2*0.0820011+2*0.0768052= ???)

Comment: @thaking `len` returns an integer, so you can multiply it: `length = len(prefix); print huffTree[1], prefix, length, length*0.124167`

Comment: well I need this to calculate this sum automatically, look at edit2, MANY thanks for HELP!

Comment: yes, i do this now; 
did you know any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question?! Just change `print huffTree[1], prefix` to `print huffTree[1], prefix, len(prefix)`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the if part of the code with

```
if len(huffTree) == 2:
      print huffTree[1], prefix, len(prefix)
```